# kotlin:I want to add the first element of a 2D array to the end

Tags: kotlin

Example:A

```
before [[20,30],[40,50],[60,70]]

after  [[20,30],[40,50],[60,70],[20,30]]
```

Example:B

```
before [[11,11],[22,22],[33,33],[44,44]]

after  [[11,11],[22,22],[33,33],[44,44],[11,11]]
```

How to copy first element of 2D array in kotlin to end of array?

I tried the add and addAll methods to add elements to the end of a 2D array, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try yourself? You should show at least some affort in solving your own problem. Btw. why tag it as Java when it is early a Kotlin question?

Comment: I accidentally typed java.Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me when I used add. Try this code:

```
val list = mutableListOf(listOf(11, 11), listOf(22, 22))
list.add(list.first())
println(list)
```

It will print:

```
[[11, 11], [22, 22], [11, 11]]
```

Make sure you create a MutableList that holds data of type List.

Comment: That creates a list instead of an array.  (In fact, a list of lists instead of an array of arrays.)  That may be fine — lists are often preferable, as they're more flexible and more widely supported — but it's not strictly answering the question as posed, and wouldn't generalise to arrays.

Comment: It happened without a hitch. Thanks